# Hiding characters typed into password field

Tags: wxpython

I am developing an student attendance application in wxpython and I need to know how to ensure that password field doesn't echo characters to the screen.
Forexample :if I give the name as moni means then it should be displayed as in format of   ****

Comment: You want your UI to display stars instead of the actual chars, as the user types in her name? How is this related to encryption?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your text control the `TE_PASSWORD` style.

(As Jørn's comment points out, this isn't "encryption" - I'm assuming you're only talking about the visual presentation of the password.)